# Why Facebook response get called continuously in mobile?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, facebook-graph-api, facebook-login

I can see in BE that `registerUser` method is get called every second but only if Facebook login happens on mobile. Last line in code `window.location.reload();` cause it. Why it happens?

```
<FacebookLogin
        appId={fbAppId}
        autoLoad={false}
        fields="name,email,picture"
        scope="public_profile"
        callback={responseFacebook}
        cssClass={`roseBackground uppercase button ${
          userNameLoggedIn ? "notallowed" : "pointer"
        }`}
        redirectUri={window.location.origin + window.location.pathname}
        isDisabled={userNameLoggedIn}
        state={eventTimeId}
      />
```

```
export const responseFacebook = responseFB => {
  let url = window.baseUrl + "registerUser";
  axios({
    method: "post",
    url: url,
    data: {
      accessToken: responseFB.accessToken,
      photoUrl: responseFB.picture.data.url,
      userName: responseFB.name,
      appId: fbAppId
    },
    headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json", crossDomain: true }
  })
    .then(responseBE => {
      // TODO: Redundant, up there almost the same.
      if (responseBE.data.error != null) {
        /*localStorage.removeItem("userIdLoggedIn");
        localStorage.removeItem("userNameLoggedIn");
        localStorage.removeItem("photoUrl");
        localStorage.removeItem("accessToken");*/
      } else {
        localStorage.setItem("jwt", responseBE.data.jwt);
        localStorage.setItem("userIdLoggedIn", responseFB.userID);
        localStorage.setItem("userNameLoggedIn", responseFB.name);
      }
      window.location.reload();
    })
```

Comment: What is this prop `callback` doing?

Comment: Callback refers to the `responseFacebook ` method you can see below.

Comment: you can put a debugger and check

Comment: Do you know how can I debug mobile?

Comment: you may not sdk

Comment: What you mean? :)